# Strange Behaviour working in netbeans IDE 7.0.1 on java swing

Tags: 12.10, java

I am using Netbeans to code java swing. I am able to the see the GUI when i run. But it says loading when i view the GUI in Netbeans IDE before running. I get some kind of linkage error. Anyone faced similar problems before??

Error

LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/netbeans/StandardModule$OneModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/EntityReference.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, netbeans 7.2 solves the problem, but I cant connect mysql on that version, so   it's not a solution.

If I undestand correctly the design window wont load, just freezes on loading... state. That's my problem too.

Comment: Exactly the design window just freezes.